# How to input a regex in string.replace?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I need some help on declaring a regex. My inputs are like the following:

```
this is a paragraph with<[1> in between</[1> and then there are cases ... where the<[99> number ranges from 1-100</[99>. 
and there are many other lines in the txt files
with<[3> such tags </[3>
```

The required output is:

```
this is a paragraph with in between and then there are cases ... where the number ranges from 1-100. 
and there are many other lines in the txt files
with such tags
```

I've tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, re, glob
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '*.txt')):
    for line in reader: 
        line2 = line.replace('<[1> ', '')
        line = line2.replace('</[1> ', '')
        line2 = line.replace('<[1>', '')
        line = line2.replace('</[1>', '')
        
        print line
```

I've also tried this (but it seems like I'm using the wrong regex syntax):

```
        line2 = line.replace('<[*> ', '')
        line = line2.replace('</[*> ', '')
        line2 = line.replace('<[*>', '')
        line = line2.replace('</[*>', '')
```

I dont want to hard-code the `replace` from 1 to 99.

Answer (score 856, accepted):

This tested snippet should do it:

```py
import re
line = re.sub(r"</?\[\d+>", "", line)
```

**Edit:** Here's a commented version explaining how it works:

```
line = re.sub(r"""
  (?x) # Use free-spacing mode.
  <    # Match a literal '<'
  /?   # Optionally match a '/'
  \[   # Match a literal '['
  \d+  # Match one or more digits
  >    # Match a literal '>'
  """, "", line)
```

Regexes are *fun!* But I would strongly recommend spending an hour or two studying the basics. For starters, you need to learn which characters are special: *"metacharacters"* which need to be escaped (i.e. with a backslash placed in front - and the rules are different inside and outside character classes.) There is an excellent online tutorial at: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). The time you spend there will pay for itself many times over. Happy regexing!

Comment: Also don't neglect The Book on Regular Expressions - _Mastering Regular Expressions_, by [Jeffrey Friedl](http://regex.info/)

Comment: Another good reference sees https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: The commented version mentions `(?x)` free-spacing mode, but that is not in the snippet.  Is that a default or something?

Comment: @RufusVS - The '(?x)' inside the regex text tells the regex engine compiler that this regex is written in free-spacing mode. You could alternatively add the: 're.VERBOSE' compilation flag to the function call.

Comment: 691 votes and a bounty for that? You'd be lucky to get a single vote nowadays. And Rufus already knew it meant free-spacing mode, he just didn't know what that was - and you have still not explained it to him.

Comment: @ridgerunner Actually, my point was, you have the expression `(?x)` present in your commented version of the pattern, but NOT in the uncommented version above it that you called `tested snippet`.  (Edit: I googled it and found out the free-spacing expression is only needed because you have comments and spaces in the explanatory version, not needed in the `tested snippet` version.  Got it now.)

Comment: Every answer on this entire site for a regex question should be written this way with comments explaining each part

Comment: If you reuse the pattern often, [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) it first. For example, `import re; mypattern=re.compile(r'a'); mypattern.sub('o', 'faa')  # 'foo'`. Instead of `'o'` you can also provide a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub:~:text=If%20repl%20is%20a%20function%2C%20it,argument%2C%20and%20returns%20the%20replacement%20string), for example `lambda matchobject: matchobject.group(0).upper()  # 'fAA'`

Answer (score 64):

`str.replace()` does fixed replacements. Use [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) instead.

Comment: Also worth noting that your pattern should look something like "</{0-1}\d{1-2}>" or whatever variant of regexp notation python uses.

Comment: What does fixed replacements mean?

Comment: @avi Probably he meant fixed word replacement rather partial word locating through regex.

Comment: fixed (literal, constant) strings

Answer (score 32):

I would go like this (regex explained in comments):

```py
import re

# If you need to use the regex more than once it is suggested to compile it.
pattern = re.compile(r"</{0,}\[\d+>")

# <\/{0,}\[\d+>
# 
# Match the character “<” literally «<»
# Match the character “/” literally «\/{0,}»
#    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{0,}»
# Match the character “[” literally «\[»
# Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
#    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Match the character “>” literally «>»

subject = """this is a paragraph with<[1> in between</[1> and then there are cases ... where the<[99> number ranges from 1-100</[99>. 
and there are many other lines in the txt files
with<[3> such tags </[3>"""

result = pattern.sub("", subject)

print(result)
```

If you want to learn more about regex I recomend to read [Regular Expressions Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449319432) by  Jan Goyvaerts and Steven Levithan.

Comment: From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#repeating-things): `{0,}` is the same as `*`, `{1,}` is equivalent to `+`, and `{0,1}` is the same as `?`. It’s better to use `*`, `+`, or `?` when you can, simply because they’re shorter and easier to read.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way

```
import re

txt='this is a paragraph with<[1> in between</[1> and then there are cases ... where the<[99> number ranges from 1-100</[99>.  and there are many other lines in the txt files with<[3> such tags </[3>'

out = re.sub("(<[^>]+>)", '', txt)
print out
```

Answer (score 15):

replace method of string objects does not accept regular expressions but only fixed strings (see documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

You have to use `re` module:

```
import re
newline= re.sub("<\/?\[[0-9]+>", "", line)
```

Comment: You should use `\d+` instead of `[0-9]+`

Answer (score 5):

don't have to use regular expression (for your sample string)

```
>>> s
'this is a paragraph with<[1> in between</[1> and then there are cases ... where the<[99> number ranges from 1-100</[99>. \nand there are many other lines in the txt files\nwith<[3> such tags </[3>\n'

>>> for w in s.split(">"):
...   if "<" in w:
...      print w.split("<")[0]
...
this is a paragraph with
 in between
 and then there are cases ... where the
 number ranges from 1-100
.
and there are many other lines in the txt files
with
 such tags
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import os, sys, re, glob

pattern = re.compile(r"\<\[\d\>")
replacementStringMatchesPattern = "<[1>"

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '*.txt')):
   for line in reader: 
      retline =  pattern.sub(replacementStringMatchesPattern, "", line)         
      sys.stdout.write(retline)
      print (retline)
```