# Python pandas with lambda apply difficulty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I am running the following function but somehow struggling to have it take the length condition into account (the if part). It simply runs the first part if the function only:

`stringDataFrame.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[^0-9]', '') if (len(x) >= 7) else x)`

it somehow only runs the `x.str.replace(r'[^0-9]', '')` part for some reason, what am I doing wrong here i have been stuck.

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows your problem?

Comment: x is a series, and len(x) is the length of that series. Do you want to check individual strings' lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) when you need to work on each value separately, because `apply` works with `all column` (`Series`).

Then instead of using [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), use [`re.sub`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658439/2901002) which works nicer for regexs:

```
print (stringDataFrame.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', x) if (len(x) >= 7) else x))
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

stringDataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'A':['gdgdg454dgd','147ooo2', '123ss45678'],
                                'B':['gdgdg454dgd','x142', '12345678a'],
                                'C':['gdgdg454dgd','xx142', '12567dd8']})

print (stringDataFrame)
             A            B            C
0  gdgdg454dgd  gdgdg454dgd  gdgdg454dgd
1      147ooo2         x142        xx142
2   123ss45678    12345678a     12567dd8

print (stringDataFrame.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', x) if (len(x) >= 7) else x))
          A         B       C
0       454       454     454
1      1472      x142   xx142
2  12345678  12345678  125678
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael this works. I had tried applymap but seems like the issue was with using `str.replace`

Comment: Just a quick one which also falls within this question. I am horrible when it comes to lambda and functions. But i want to have two conditions by adding an additional `x.contains("tel | cel | cell", case=False)`. This would then mean the formula should look something like this `stringDataFrame.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', x) if ((len(x) >= 7) & (x.contains("tel | cel | cell", case=False))) else x)`  @jezrael

Comment: You need plain python, try `print (stringDataFrame.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', x) if (len(x) >= 7) and (any(ext in x.lower() for ext in ['cel','tel','cell'])) else x))`

Comment: Thanks @jazrael i will iterate through the results