# How to use lambda to apply style to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe, and I would like to highlight the cells red, where the word "BBC" appears.

Looking at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203959/conditionally-format-python-pandas-cell) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994408/python-pandas-with-lambda-apply-difficulty) I tried the below:

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color: red" if x == "BBC News" else "background-color: green"])
```

or

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color: red" if v == "BBC News" else "background-color: green" for v in x], axis=None)
```

[image]

But this doesn't color anything.  FWIW, I don't know what the `x` or `v` are in the examples I used. I assume `x` is a cell, and `v` would be a part of the cell?

How can I conditinally format cells?  I'd also be adding others, i.e. if "CNN" appears in a cell, color yellow, etc.

Edit: I tried simply `df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color: green"])` and nothing happened (same if I used `#ff0000` or `rgb(0,0,255)`).

To be explicit, I'm doing:

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color: #ff0000" if v['newsSource'] == "BBC News" else "background-color: #ffff00"], axis=None)
df.to_html("styletest.html")
```

So I want the coloring visible in the ***HTML DOCUMENT*** not the dataframe itself necessarily.

Comment: Could you try color code instead of string

Comment: @NerdicSapo - Do you mean hex, i.e. #FFFFF?  I tried replacing `red` with `#ff0000` and `green` with `#ffff00` (just to test if it wokrs), and no colors show.

Comment: You want to change check first column, which is 'newsSource'. You need to access column.

Comment: @rahlf23 - Where does that go, `lamba x['newsSource']`? I tried adding that to [...if x['newsSource'] == "BBC News"...]` but nothing changed.  It may help to state that while typically I am pretty good at understanding list comprehensions, I have no idea at all what the `x` or `v` are in my second example, so clarifying that might help my understanding.  Edit: Just saw your edited comment. One second let me apply.

Comment: @BruceWayne x is each column/row and v is each element within?
Also are you looking for `v == "BBC News"` for just `"BBC" in v`?

Comment: @AsheKetchum - Preferably, I'd like to search for `[word] in v`, so I don't have to know the exact name.  I have no idea what the `x` and `v` are, I was just following other examples I found. :/

Comment: @rahlf23 - Thanks for the edit, I tried the code but still no coloring :/

Comment: Let's discuss (hopefully this link works): https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176733/pandas-discussion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, this should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['BBC News','something','Test1'],
                    ['The Wall Street Journal','something else','Test2'],
                    ['BBC News','something else entirely','Test3']],
                    columns=['newsSource','description','title'])

html = df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background: red" if 'BBC' in x['newsSource'] and idx==0 else "" for idx, v in enumerate(x)], axis = 1).set_table_attributes('border="1" class="dataframe table table-hover table-bordered"').render()

with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Explanation:

The `lambda` operator allows you to `apply` the following `["background: red" if 'BBC' in x['newsSource'] and idx==0 else "" for idx, v in enumerate(x)]`to every row of your `df` (specified by `axis=1`), where `x` is each individual row of your `df`.

In English, this means change to `"background: red"` if the string `'BBC'` is contained in `x['newsSource']`, i.e. the `'newsSource'` column of the row `x` of `df`. The extra logic specifying `idx==0` means only the first cell of that row `x`, for which we have to `enumerate(x)` in order to track the current column index `idx`. Otherwise, do not change the background color, using `else ""`. Hope that's clear!

Comment: Yeah, that works. Column B and C are highlighted red.  Now, we need to apply that logic to text instead of numbers :D

Comment: Hayoooo - the whole row highlights red! We're getting somewhere! Now, how could I make just the cell the word appears in red?

Comment: oh, you wanted to display it in the html?

Comment: @AsheKetchum - What do you mean?  Yeah, I was referring to the HTML.  Can you color the **dataframe** itself somehow, which may not reflect when doing `to_html()`??

Comment: @BruceWayne Yeah, like if you just say df.style.apply(highlight, axis=1) it prints the DataFrame with the desired coloring, for an interactive environment at least

Comment: Thanks so much @rahlf23!  This works.  Now, it's a little much to ask, but could you maybe break down that lambda function, in "english"?  I'm trying to make sense of it.  (Mainly, so I can learn how to use this for other words/columns).  Yay!!

Comment: (@rahlf23 - I get the `set_table_attributes` part mostly, so no need to explain that. It's the lambda craziness that I don't quite get :P)

Comment: Thanks **so much** for your help! (Ash too!)

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if something like this works?

```
def highlight_txt(s, txt):

    has_bbc = s.apply(lambda x: '')
    bbc = s.index.tolist().index('newsSource')
    has_bbc[bbc] = 'background-color: yellow' if txt in s[bbc] else 'background-color: green'

    return has_bbc

df.style.apply(lambda x: highlight_txt(x, 'BBC', axis=1))
```

Comment: Nothing happend :(   FYI if I call `type(df)` just before the `.apply` line, I do get `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`  Edit: Still nothing, after the edit

Comment: k try again? I forgot to change the `if 'a' in s[bbc]` to `if 'BBC' in s[bbc]`

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: I feel like the logic should be right now xD, it worked for my simple df
`df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'], data=[['b', 'a', 'd'], ['c', 'x', 'f'], ['b', 's', 'w']])`

Comment: That doesn't highlight anything for me. [Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeOyr.jpg) (sorry it's a screenshot, but I don't know a better way to show the code)

Answer (score 0):

I would separate this to a function for clarity, and then iterate over the rows:

```
def highlight_cell(row):
    background = []
    for cell in row:
        color = 'background-color: green'
        if 'BBC' in cell:
            color = 'background-color: red'
        elif 'CNN' in cell:
            color = 'background-color: yellow'
        background.append(color)
    return background

df.style.apply(highlight_cell, axis=1)
```

Comment: Nothing happens, no coloring :(