# Remove Multiple Blanks In DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How do I remove multiple spaces between two strings in python.

e.g:-

```
"Bertug 'here multiple blanks' Mete" => "Bertug        Mete"
```

to

```
"Bertug Mete"
```

Input is read from an .xls file. I have tried using split() but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
import pandas as pd , string , re

dataFrame = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Bertug\\Desktop\\example.xlsx")

#names1 =  ''.join(dataFrame.Name.to_string().split()) 

print(type(dataFrame.Name))

#print(dataFrame.Name.str.split())
```

Let me know where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: whats problem whit this: names1 =  ' '.join(dataFrame.Name.to_string().split())

Comment: @Bertug please add example how your data is looks like.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I think use `replace`:

```
df.Name = df.Name.replace(r'\s+', ' ', regex=True)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Bertug     Mete','a','Joe    Black']})
print (df)
              Name
0  Bertug     Mete
1                a
2     Joe    Black

df.Name = df.Name.replace(r'\s+', ' ', regex=True)
#similar solution
#df.Name = df.Name.str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')
print (df)
          Name
0  Bertug Mete
1            a
2    Joe Black
```

Comment: I'm using Python 3 and this didn't work for me. Perhaps the solution is Python 2. This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658439/2763005

Comment: Using Python 3, df["Name"].str.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True) worked. Notice the additional str.

Comment: remember to add an r before the regex if working with pandas in python 3```r'\s+'```

Comment: use df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\s+', ' ', regex=True) to strip duplicate white spaces in all the columns.