# How to Replace 2 Backslashes Between $ Symbols with 4 Backslashes using Python and Regex?

Tags: python, regex, mathjax

I would like to replace all double backslashes `\\` enclosed between $ symbols or $$ symbols with four backslashes `\\\\`.

E.g., I want to convert `some \\ random text $ 5\\ 6$` to `some \\ random text $ 5\\\\ 6$`, and `some $5x^2 \$ random text $$ 5 \\ 6$$` to `some $5x^2 \$ random text $$ 5 \\\\ 6$$`.

How can I do this using regex and Python?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: Try if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace) can answer.

Comment: Could this be an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe you could use [raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals).

Comment: I need to replace double backslashes with 4 backslashes so that mathjax will render properly after rendering markdown.

Comment: To make sure this is not an escape problem: wbat is the source of the text? How does it get into Python?

Comment: I've created a website using django, and I allow users create posts in markdown (similar to on SO). When I try to render certain posts which contain \\ between $ symbols, the markdown renderer which I am using converts \\ to \.

Comment: @Jack Don't try to escape your users' markup for them. You'll create more problems than you'll solve. Give them a preview and let them deal with it. A little documentation about which flavor (maybe even the exact renderer) of Markdown you're using might also help.

Comment: Also, you can't do this properly with regex. (Or if you can, it'll be a nightmare regex. It's the wrong tool for the job.) You need a parser to handle matching delimiters that can contain other nested elements correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

Pattern: `(?<!\\)([$]+)([^$]*?)\\([^$]*?)(?<!\\)\1`
Substitution: `\1\2\\\\\\\\\3\1`

Examples using your provided tests: https://regex101.com/r/X9lGCF/2

Rough explanation of pattern:

`(?<!\\)([$]+)` - Match and capture at least one unescaped `$`; the `(?<!\\)` is a negative lookbehind to make sure the `$`'s aren't prefixed with a backslash

`([^$]*?)\\([^$]*?)` - Capture the text between the first matched `$` sequence and the same initially matched `$` sequence on either side of the `\\`

`(?<!\\)\1` - Reuse the initially matched `$` sequence in our pattern (this enforces the surrounding `$` sequences to be the same length; e.g. not matching things like `$\\$$`), ensuring that the last sequence is also unescaped

The substitution will replace the backslashes (they're escaped, hence why we use 8 of them to get 4 backslashes) with the surrounding captured text and `$` sequences.