# Replace Substring with another but only if a certain substring follows it

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace the substring 'gta' with substring 'cat'. But the condition is that 'gta' immediately has to be followed by substring 'dog'.

Example: 'gtagtadogcat' would become 'gtacatdogcat'

The part I'm struggling with is trying to write the program to find 'gta' and validate that 'dog' is behind it and if true, change 'gta' to 'cat'.

Comment: you could take a look at regular expressions in python if you wanted the most flexible way of doing substring replacements. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace

Comment: ...in other words, you're trying to replace `gtadog` with `catdog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> 'gtagtadogcat'.replace('gta'+'dog', 'cat'+'dog')
'gtacatdogcat'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
old_string = 'gtagtadogcat'
print(old_string.replace('gtacat','dogcat'))
```

output: `gtagtadogcat`

Comment: I think you need to change your last line to `print(old_string.replace('gtadog','catdog'))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

```
re.sub('gta(dog)', r'cat\1', 'gtagtadogcat')
```

Output:

```
'gtacatdogcat'
```

*Edit: You would not need a forloop if you put in the whole string. Here is an example:

```
re.sub('gta(dog)', r'cat\1', 'gtagtadogcat_moretextgta_lastgtadog')
```

Output:

```
'gtacatdogcat_moretextgta_lastcatdog'
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I forgot to mention that the Example was just one combination of what could be put in. I need to make sure that if dog comes up multiple times, and if there's a 'gta' in front of it, it'll change it to 'cat'. The example I gave just has it coming up once. Would I need a For loop to cycle through the string in that regard?

Comment: I have edited my post.