# Digit Numbers Negation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to negate part of the IP address and get only the last two octets
for example:

```
IP_Add1 192.168.10.1 LAN 10
```

I only want the last two octets of the IP Add (10.1), so I need my output looks like this:

```
IP_Add1 10.1 LAN 10
```

I have already tried with the following code, but I get an empty list [] as a result. any help?

```
str_2 = '''IP_Add1 192.168.10.1 LAN 10
IP_Add1 192.168.10.1 LAN 20
IP_Add1 192.168.20.1 LAN 30
IP_Add1 192.168.30.1 LAN 40
'''

print(re.findall(r"\w+ [\d]{3}.[\d]{3}.[\d]{2}.[\d]{1}", str_2))
```

Comment: You're using `re.findall` where you should probably be using `re.sub` (you'd need a different pattern too). Here is a link: [How to input a regex in string.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace)

Comment: You might want to focus on solving a *single* IP address, and once you have that, add in handling a sequence of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have already tried with the following code, but I get an empty list []

On the contrary, when I run you code, I get the following:

```
import re
str_2 = '''IP_Add1 192.168.10.1 LAN 10
IP_Add1 192.168.10.1 LAN 20
IP_Add1 192.168.20.1 LAN 30
IP_Add1 192.168.30.1 LAN 40
'''

print(re.findall(r"\w+ [\d]{3}.[\d]{3}.[\d]{2}.[\d]{1}", str_2))
#['IP_Add1 192.168.10.1', 'IP_Add1 192.168.10.1', 'IP_Add1 192.168.20.1', 'IP_Add1 192.168.30.1']
```

This is because `re.findall` will:

> Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.

But based on your wording, what you actually want to do is better accomplished using `re.sub`:

```
res = re.sub(r"(?<=IP_Add\d )\d{3}\.\d{3}\.(?=\d{2}\.\d{1})", "", str_2)
print(res)
#IP_Add1 10.1 LAN 10
#IP_Add1 10.1 LAN 20
#IP_Add1 20.1 LAN 30
#IP_Add1 30.1 LAN 40
```

If you wanted your results in a list, you can call the `splitlines()` method:

```
print(res.splitlines())
#['IP_Add1 10.1 LAN 10',
# 'IP_Add1 10.1 LAN 20',
# 'IP_Add1 20.1 LAN 30',
# 'IP_Add1 30.1 LAN 40']
```

The regular expression pattern used in `sub` is the following:

- `(?<=IP_Add\d )`: Look-behind for the literal string `"IP_Add"` followed by exactly one digit and one space
- `\d{3}\.\d{3}\.`: Three digits followed by a literal period, followed by another 3 digits and a literal period.
- `(?=\d{2}\.\d{1})`: Look-ahead for two digits, a period, and then one digit.

Comment: thanks @pault, i think this what i wanted to achieve, but I am wondering why i don't get the same result with the following code print(re.findall(r"\w+ [^\d]{3}\.[^\d]{3}\.[\d]{2}.[\d]{1}", str_2))

Comment: @user3682875 test our your patterns on https://regex101.com/ and you'll see what the meaning is. For example, here is a [link](https://regex101.com/r/35xtxf/1) to the pattern I supplied in this answer.