# How do I remove these stop words with word boundaries?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, stop-words

Trying to remove these stop words when they are surrounded by a word boundary.
It's not working, any ideas?

```
stop_words = ['industries','inc','cor','enterprises','international','studios','llc','ltd','systems','housewares','incorporation','corporation','electronics','group','usa', 'entertainment','distributors',',','exclusive','artist','illustrator', 'actor', 'director', 'director','editor', 'translator', 'creator', 'photographer', 'ntributor','tm','writer','publisher','producer', 'performer', 'pl', 'author','\(\)', 'co', 'announcement']

for i in stop_words:
    df_input['clean_brand'] = df_input.clean_brand.replace('\b%s\b' %i,'', 
    regex=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to input a regex in string.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace)

Comment: What's your input and what's wrong with the output?