# Escape single quote in a string with back slash

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Hello I have a string like this

```
"'Ade', 'Danidee', 'Lamarr', 'O'Connor', 'Austino', 'N'golo',"
```

I need to be able to escape the single Quote character so the output will be like this

```
"'Ade', 'Danidee', 'Lamarr', 'O\'Connor', 'Austino', 'N\'golo',"
```

I have tried something like

Splitting the string with coma(,) in to a list

loop through it and checking if single quote is in each item

Then

```
item.replace("'", "\'")
```

Append it to a new list and join it with (,) again

Is there a way I can do it directly without going through all that?

I need to be able to do something like

```
str.replace("'", "\'")
```

But that will replace the whole single quotes

`'Ade'` will become `Ade` i don't want that

Thanks.

Comment: Another workaround could be using `"""` for your outer quotes, and `"` for the inner ones

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace

Comment: Your input is broken. It would be better to fix whatever produces it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import re
text = "'Ade', 'Danidee', 'Lamarr', 'O'Connor', 'Austino', 'N'golo',"
print( re.sub(r"(\w)'(\w)",r"\1\'\2",text) )

'Ade', 'Danidee', 'Lamarr', 'O\'Connor', 'Austino', 'N\'golo',
```

Comment: This worked, thank you, what also worked is this `re.sub(r"\b\'\b", r"\\'", text)`

Answer (score -1):

One way can be:

```
print("\"'Ade', 'Danidee', 'Lamarr', 'O\\'Connor', 'Austino', 'N\\'golo',\"")
```