# Lambda expression in python won't give the correct output

Tags: python

I am working on a machine learning problem, and I am trying to write a lambda function to remove the punctuation from a pandas column, unfortunately the lamda expression is not working as expected

```
combi['tidy_tweet'] = combi['tidy_tweet'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("[^a-zA-Z#]", " "))
```

The above expression leaves the column intact, while I expect it to remove the punctuation.

Does anybody have any idea what is wrong with the lambda expression above?

Comment: You are trying to `replace` using regex but unfortunately is not supported. You need to use `re` module. This question has answer here [How to input a regex in string.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace)

Comment: Can you provide `tidy_tweet` dataframe?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to replace by a regular expression, then you need to `import re` and use `re.sub()` instead of `str.replace()`:

```
 ...lambda x: re.sub("[^a-zA-Z#]", "", x)
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` arg in your lambda function is a pure string that calls built-in `str.replace` method which does not operate on regex patterns.
Instead you may just apply [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) function with `regex` flavour:

```
combi['tidy_tweet'] = combi['tidy_tweet'].replace(r'[^a-zA-Z#]', ' ', regex=True)
```