# How to use the re module to join all lines in a text file, into a single, continuous string?

Tags: regex, string

I'm getting a little stuck here. Say I have a text file that reads:

AAAAAA BBBBBBB

SDSDDSDSD CCCC HEY

And I want Python to convert it into one, continuous string that reads:

AAAAAABBBBBBBSDSDDSDSDCCCCHEY

Only thing is, I need to use the **re** module. How do I go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to remove all spaces and newlines. Also see: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/5658369/11981207](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5658369/11981207)

Comment: I had typed the following, but was getting an empty result:

`file = open('myfile.txt', 'r').read()`

`oneline = re.sub('\n', '', file)`

...but to no avail. If I try to print `oneline`, the only thing that comes up is: `""`

Instead, I want the whole string.

Comment: I think you're missing an `r`.  re.sub(**r**'\n', '', file)

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that, too, and whenever I try to print `oneline`, I still just get `"`. :(

Comment: What happens when you print `file`?

Comment: Only empty space appears! :O

Comment: Try double checking that you have content in `myfile.txt`. Maybe the file hasn't been saved yet and is still blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try stripping *all* whitespace characters:

```
inp = """AAAAAA BBBBBBB
SDSDDSDSD CCCC HEY"""
output = re.sub(r'\s+', '', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
AAAAAABBBBBBBSDSDDSDSDCCCCHEY
```

Comment: I kind of see what you're saying, but what if `inp` is a really big text file, and you don't want to copy-paste all of the contents of the text file? I tried doing `inp = open('myfile.txt', 'r').read()`, but that wasn't working for me.

Comment: Well if your strategy be to read each line one by one, then you could still use my answer to strip whitespace; the problem is mostly still the same.

Comment: If I were to try that, would I have to create a for loop for each individual line? If so, how could I do that? I appreciate you being so patient with me.

Comment: What is the actual output you expect here?