# String Replace with word match

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable in which I need to replace it with a word match.

Currently this is my logic

```
string = "This is a test"
x = string.replace("Test", "")
```

How can I make sure here cap T can match the entire word for test as Test?

Comment: Do you only want to replace it with empty?

Comment: Read all answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace

Comment: yes want to replace it with empty