# Leave only letters and numbers in the string using a regex, in pyton

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

i have string, for example: '1212kk , l '
With a regex I have to strip out everything except numbers and letters and get this: '1212kkl'

Comment: @Dschoni Then what do you think `re.sub` is doing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to input a regex in string.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace)

Comment: Sorry, that was too fast ;)

Comment: Give me regex for X is not a valid question. Please read [ask] and [edit] what you tried into you question

Comment: `re.sub('[\W_]+', '', str)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`str.isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) which chekcs if its either letter or digit:

```
text = "1212kk , l"

# Option 1:
# The `x for x in text` goes on string characters
# The `if x.isalnum()` filters in only letters and digits
# The `''.join()` takes the filtered list and joins it to a string
filtered = ''.join([x for x in text if x.isalnum()])

# Option 2:
# Applay `filter` of `text` characters that `str.isalnum` returns `True` for them
# The `''.join()` takes the filtered list and joins it to a string
filtered = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, text))

# 1212kkl
print(filtered )
```