# Python Regular Expression String Substitution Questions

Tags: python

I have the text `"languageType" : "en"`,  and I want to replace it with `en`. How do I do it using replace? I've tried this so far so it's not working

```
lang = s.split(":")[0].replace("[\"']", "", -1).strip()
print(lang)
```

But I keep getting `"en"`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Seems like you might have a key-value JSON entry there. How about `json.loads`?

Comment: `s.split(":")[1]`

Comment: What I want is to do with the replace method.

Comment: The replace method doesn't accept a regular expression, but rather a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace

Comment: I understood your explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The replace method doesn't accept a regular expression, but rather a string. To replace with a regex use `re.sub()`. See [How to input a regex in string.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace)

I've made the same mistake before, myself.