# Implement regular expression in Python to replace every occurence of "meshname = x" in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, io

I want to replace every line in a textfile with " " which starts with "meshname = " and ends with any letter/number and underscore combination. I used regex's in CS but I never really understood the different notations in Python. Can you help me with that?

Is this the right regex for my problem and how would i transform that into a Python regex?

```
m.e.s.h.n.a.m.e.' '.=.' '.{{_}*,{0,...,9}*,{a,...,z}*,{A,...,Z}*}*

x.y = Concatenation of x and y  
' ' = whitespace  
{x} = set containing x  
x* = x.x.x. ... .x or empty word
```

What would the script look like in order to replace every string/line in a file containing meshname = ... with the Python regex? Something like this?

```
fin = open("test.txt", 'r')
data = fin.read()
data = data.replace("^meshname = [[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*[_]*]+", "")
fin.close()
fin = open("test.txt", 'w')
fin.write(data)
fin.close()
```

or is this completely wrong? I've tried to get it working with this approach, but somehow it never matched the right string: [How to input a regex in string.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace)

Comment: The regex is messed up, but you can't use a regex in `str.replace`, you need `re.sub`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace, but that didn't work. My regex is probably wrong, yeah ;/

Comment: Yeah, it should be `data = re.sub(r'^meshname = .*\w$', ' ', data, flags=re.M)`

Comment: Why `[[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*[_]*]+`? Just use `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` or `\w+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the current code logic, you can use

```py
data = re.sub(r'^meshname = .*\w$', ' ', data, flags=re.M)
```

The `re.sub` will replace with a space any line that matches

- `^` - line start (note the `flags=re.M` argument that makes sure the *multiline* mode is on)
- `meshname` - a `meshname` word
- `=`  -  a  `=`  string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\w` - a letter/digit/`_`
- `$` - line end.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess my regex skills are a bit rusty.