# How to find a character in string and replace it and the following one in python

Tags: python, string

I'm using an API that returns § characters with a color code (1-9 or a-h) which I want to eliminate (§ and following character). Their purpose is for color formatting but I'm not using that and my method iterates through a string to remove them but could not find a better way and it fees too hacky and buggy. Is there like a parameter for the `str.replace` function that removes the letter after the found character?

Comment: Replace all the characters that are not alphanumeric. [How to input a regex in string.replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "eliminate" the precise pattern with `regular expressions` using the `sub` method:

```
import re
def clean_string(s):
    return re.sub(r"\$[1-9a-h]", "", s)

clean_string("foo $4 - bar $f")
# > 'foo  - bar '
```

If you want more flexibility, you can match any `non whitespace character` following $ with `\S`:

```
import re
def clean_string(s):
    return re.sub(r"\$\S", "", s)
```

Comment: is there any way i could use like * or something to represent any character for more flexibility?

Comment: Yes you can. I updated the answer. If it's too broad (because it also catches symbols after the `$`), you can specify any character you want between brackets, like `r"\$[\wéàÉü]"`.