# Find a regex and modify only a part of it in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-re

Imagine I have a few values like

```
test_val1 = 'E 18TH ST AND A AVE'
test_val2 = 'E 31ST ST AND A AVE'
```

I want to find the 18th, 31st, etc., and replace it with 18/31 - basically removing the suffix but keep the entire string as such.

Expected value

```
test_val1 = 'E 18 ST AND A AVE'
test_val2 = 'E 31 ST AND A AVE'
```

Please note that I do not want to remove the "St" which corresponds to 'street', so a blind replacement is not possible.

My approach was to use below (for 'th' at the moment), but it doesn't work since the function cannot keep the value/text in memory to return it.

```
import regex as re
test_val1.replace('\d{1,}TH', '\d{1,}', regex=True)
```

I have a column full of these values, so a solution that I can run/apply on a Pnadas column would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the following sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Test": ['E 18TH ST AND A AVE', 'E 31ST ST AND A AVE']})
```

```
                  Test
0  E 18TH ST AND A AVE
1  E 31ST ST AND A AVE
```

this

```
df.Test = df.Test.str.replace(r'(\d+)(TH|ST)', lambda m: m.group(1), regex=True)
```

produces

```
                Test
0  E 18 ST AND A AVE
1  E 31 ST AND A AVE
```

Is that what you are looking for? Check out the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) for more details.

The `lambda` function is used as a `repl` function ("replace") whose returns replace the pattern matches in the strings. Per definition it gets as argument the respective [match object](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#match-objects) and has to return a string, usually derived from the match object, but it could be totally unrelated. The function here returns the content of the 1. capture group via the [match object method `group`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#re.Match.group): The `(\d+)`-part.

Comment: Can you please explain what the lambda function is doing? Thnaks!

Comment: @PruthviReddy Sure, see the edit of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned it doesn't work since the function cannot keep the value/text in memory to return it. Is it mandatory NOT to store the value to a different variable?

```
t1 = 'E 18TH ST AND A AVE'

for t1 in column:    #t1 is address in the dataframe column

t2 = t1.split()
    
t2[1] = re.sub(r'(TH|ST)', '',t2[1])
    
 t1 = ' '.join(t2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help with the REGEX replacement. It seems like the function that you want to use is actually `sub` instead of `replace`.
This is the function signature:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])
```

Check the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub).

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace) is an outstanding answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a sample value

```
test_val = 'E 32ND ST AND A AVE'
```

I wrapped it in a quick function

```
import regex as re
def street_suffix_remover(in_val):
    for x in re.findall(r"(\d{1,}TH|\d{1,}RD|\d{1,}ST|\d{1,}ND)", in_val):
        in_val = in_val.replace(x, re.sub(r"TH|ST|RD|ND","", x)) 
    return(in_val)
```

Test it on a sample

```
street_suffix_remover(test_val)
```

Output

```
E 32 ST AND A AVE
```

Ran it on a dataframe as below

```
test_df['address'] = test_df.apply(lambda row:street_suffix_remover(row['address']), axis=1)
```

Comment: A couple of remarks: (1) Performance-wise it's better to avoid the use of `apply` if there are more native Pandas methods available. `df.column.str` gives you access to a range of string methods which operate _vectorized_ on the column. (2) The regex part is a bit too convoluted :)) (3) If you go the `apply` route then I'd do it this way: `test_df.address = test_df.address.apply(street_suffix_remover)`.