# python3 regex: how to remove u[0-9]{4} from string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

python 3.9

```
s = "aaau0004bbbbu0001"
s.replace(r"u[0-9]{4}", "")
'aaau0004bbbbu0001'
```

How to get the result 'aaabbbb'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use regex in `.replace` as regex in Python is handled by [`re`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace) module ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658369/how-to-input-a-regex-in-string-replace)).

Using `re.sub` you can do this:

```py
import re

s = "aaau0004bbbbu0001"
result = re.sub(r"u[0-9]{4}", "", s)
print(result)  # Outputs: "aaabbbb"
```